# How to extract weighted average values?

Tags: sql, firebird

Lets suppose i have such table:

```
IDofemployee category value importance range  date
1            1        2     5          1       2013-04-17
1            1        3     4          2       2013-04-17
1            2        4     3          1       2013-04-17
2            1        7     2          1       2013-04-18
2            1        3     2          2       2013-04-18
```

And now i would like to have as result of SQL query in firebird something like this:

(where range is the same it should take average of all values with the same range, but separately for different employees)

```
emp    wAVG                           date
1      (([2*5+4*3]/2)+[3*4])/3 =7.6   2013-04-17
2      (7*2+3*2)/2=10                 2013-04-18
```

so it is because in emp1 it has to take avg from row 1 and 3 because
range is in both case =1 so it takes from row1 = 2*5(value*importance)
from row3 =4*3
sum 2*5 + 4*3 and this sum is
divided by 2 because there are 2 rows with the same range

Comment: Your calculation is not a weighted average, in that case it would be (2*5+3*4+4*3)/12 = 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
select IDofemployee, date, sum(sa) / sum(sc) as wAVG
from (
   select IDofemployee, date, sum(value*importance) / count(value) sa, count(value) sc
   from TAB
   group by IDofemployee, range, date
)
group by IDofemployee, date
```

Note that if both `value` and `importance` are of integer type you need to cast them to the float or the result of division would be integer too (ie the answer you'd get would be 7 not 7.6). To cast replace

```
sum(value*importance) / count(value) sa
```

in the above query with

```
cast(sum(value*importance) / count(value) as double precision) sa
```

Also, `value` and `date` are keywords and shouldn't be used as field names.

Comment: Ok, these are only examples... Why / count(value) ? Can there be anything else? Sometimes value can be the same...

Comment: count(FieldName) only counts rows where the specified field is not NULL. But if you can't have NULLs in `importance` and `value` fields then it shouldn't make difference...